# Sencha Touch 1.1.0 + Compass 0.11

Tags: sencha-touch, sass, compass-sass

I am having great trouble getting started with theming for Sencha Touch. The problem is apparently a version conflict, according to some sources.

```
vegard@vegard-desktop:~/phonegap/sencha-touch/resources/sass$ compass compile
   exists ../css
unchanged android.scss
unchanged apple.scss
unchanged bb6.scss
  compile sencha-touch.scss
NoMethodError on line 9 of /home/vegard/phonegap/sencha-touch/resources/sass/../themes/lib/theme_images.rb: undefined method `inline_image_string' for #<Sass::Script::Functions::EvaluationContext:0x7f6851732fd8>
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

[This forum thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?128059-SASS-Errors-in-Version-1.1) seems to indicate that it is a version conflict, and that I should use `gem install compass --pre` to get the correct version, along with a specific version of `chunky_png`. [Sencha themselves](http://www.sencha.com/blog/an-introduction-to-theming-sencha-touch) have updated to tell us that I need the pre-release (meaning 0.11.beta.7 as of today, even though 0.11.1 is ready):

> Update 4/18/11: As of Sencha Touch
>   1.1, we are using the beta version of Compass, and have updated the line
>   below accordingly.
>
> `gem install compass --pre`
>
> Note: You may need to install using `sudo gem install…` for administrative
>   privileges.

I still cannot get it to work, and I get the error above, even if I've tried the following versions of Compass:

- 0.11.1
- 0.11.beta.7
- 0.11.beta.6
- 0.10.6

I've uninstalled the installed version between each try. I've tried with various versions of `chunky_png`. None of them work.

Comment: Maybe try to remove it first, and removing SASS too, then install first SASS with --pre and then Compass. The versions are a  little tricky to get right